# Firefox remove basic authorization info

Tags: javascript, firefox, basic-authentication

As you know Firefox remembers the basic authentication info for a user once the user logs in.

How do I remove this programmatically using javascript?

Scenario:

1. User logs in
2. An ajax request using basic authentication is sent to the server
3. If successful, firefox then remembers authentication info
4. If user logs out, firefox still remembers it, unless browser is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible from within the sandboxed environment of a script running in a web page.

It's possible for a Firefox *extension* to do this (as Web Developer Toolbar does), but not a web page